# Split string and delete item that contains substring

Tags: mysql, string, split

I need to transform string in MySQL from this

```
44|UK 46|47 - Out of stock|XL|Large|52
```

to this

```
44|46|XL|Large|52
```

So delimiter is "|" and need to delete substring with " - Out of stock"

Answer (score 0):

There is no Split function natively available in MySQL. Its trivial to do it after you have fetched the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP in conjunction with MySQL, query for the field and then use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode) to split the data:

```
$sql = 'SELECT yourfield FROM yourtable WHERE id = theid';
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(false !== $query) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $items = explode('|', $row['yourfield']);

        foreach($items as $key => $item)
            if($item === ' - Out of stock')
                unset($items[$key]);

        var_dump($items);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use plain MySQL. PHP is not using in this project.

Comment: Since that's the case, there is no native split function in MySQL, unfortunately.